# Compute the length of an ideal in polynomial rings

Tags: vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $k = \mathbb{F}_2$ and $R=k[x,y,z]$, and suppose $I \subseteq R$ is an ideal of $R$. I want to show that $\dim_k (R/I) = \text{length}_R (R/I)$.

For instance, in my specific example, $I = (x^2,y^2,z^2,xyz)$. Obviously a $k$-basis for $R/I$ is made of all the monomials that are not multiples of $x^2, y^2, z^2$ or $xyz$, i.e. a basis can be $\{1,x,y,z,xy,xz,yz\}$. Since it is of cardinality $7$, we can state that $\dim_k (R/I) = 7$.

My teacher then states that we can deduce from this that $\text{length}_R(R/I)$ is also $7$.

Any idea on how to prove this ?

Comment: Can you find a maximal submodule in your example?

Comment: In general, the equality you write is not correct. If $I$ is a maximal ideal ideal, then length of $R/I$ is one, but $\dim_k(R/I)$ may be larger.

Comment: Mariano Suarez-Alvarez, I think that $\cfrac{R/I}{(yz)}$ should be a maximal submodule, shouldn't it ?
Mohan, I disagree, if $I = (x,y,z)$ is maximal in $R$, $length_R (R/I) = 1$ but a basis of $(x,y,z)$ is $(1)$ and thus $dim_k (R/I)$ is also $1$.

Comment: I did not say any thing about your special case, where indeed you have radical of $I$ is an $\mathbb{F}_2$ rational maximal ideal. But, in general, your equality is wrong. Also, the length in your case is 8, not 7, since $xyz$ is another element which is linearly independent from the seven you write.

Comment: My bad I forgot to pu $xyz$ in the ideal (so it's indeed 7)

Comment: I might have solve my problem, tell me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: On one hand, $dim_k(R/I) = l_k(R/I)$ because $k$ is a field, $\geq l_R(R/I)$ because every chain of $R$-submodules is a chain of $k$-submodules.

On the other hand, write $n = dim_k(R/I)$. Then $R/I = R/(x_1, \cdots, x_n)$ for some $x_1, \cdots, x_n \in R = \mathbb{F}_2 [x,y,z]$. Thus we order $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ by polynomial degree (i.e. $deg(x_1) \leq \cdots \leq deg(x_n)$), then a $R$-submodule chain of length $n$ can be : 

$$0 = \frac{R/I}{(x_1, \cdots, x_n)} \subsetneq \frac{R/I}{(x_2, \cdots, x_n)} \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq \frac{R/I}{(x_n)} \subsetneq R/I$$

Answer (score 0):

As it was noticed in the comments, $\dim_k(R/I)$ may differ from $\operatorname{length}_R(R/I)$, in general.
For instance, $\dim_{\mathbb R}\left(\mathbb R[X]/(X^2+1)\right)=2$ and $\operatorname{length}_{\mathbb R[X]}\left(\mathbb R[X]/(X^2+1)\right)=1$.

However, there are some important cases where the equality holds.

> 1) If $K$ is an algebraically closed field, $R=K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ and $I\subset R$ is a zero-dimensional ideal, then $\dim_K(R/I)=\operatorname{length}_R(R/I).$

This follows easily from $R/\mathfrak m\simeq K$ for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $R$.

For instance, $$\dim_{\mathbb C}\left(\mathbb C[X,Y]/(X^2-Y^3,X^3-Y^2)\right)=\operatorname{length}_{\mathbb C[X,Y]}\left(\mathbb C[X,Y]/(X^2-Y^3,X^3-Y^2)\right).$$
In order to compute $\dim_{\mathbb C}\left(\mathbb C[X,Y]/(X^2-Y^3,X^3-Y^2)\right)$ notice that with respect to degree lexicographical order $X^2-Y^3,X^3-Y^2$ form a Grobner basis, so the initial ideal is generated by $X^3,Y^3$, and this shows us that $\dim_{\mathbb C}\left(\mathbb C[X,Y]/(X^2-Y^3,X^3-Y^2)\right)$ equals $\dim_{\mathbb C}\left(\mathbb C[X,Y]/(X^3,Y^3)\right)=9$. (See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3509733/on-the-primary-decomposition-of-an-ideal/3515216?noredirect=1#comment7231445_3515216).)

> 2) If $K$ is a field, $R=K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ and $I\subset R$ is an ideal with $\mathfrak m^{i+1}\subseteq I\subseteq\mathfrak m^i$, where $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ with $R/\mathfrak m\simeq K$ and $i$ a positive integer, then $\dim_K(R/I)= \operatorname{length}_R(R/I).$

In this case use the short exact sequence $0\to\mathfrak m^i/I\to R/I\to R/\mathfrak m^i\to 0$, and notice that $\mathfrak m^i/I$ is an $(R/\mathfrak m)$-module (vector space).

The example in the question falls in the case 2) since $I=(x^2,y^2,z^2,xyz)$ has the property $\mathfrak m^3\subset I\subset\mathfrak m^2$, where $\mathfrak m=(x,y,z)$.

We can generalize 2) as follows:

> 3) If $K$ is a field, $R=K[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ and $I\subset R$ is an ideal with $\sqrt I=\mathfrak m$, where $\mathfrak m$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ with $R/\mathfrak m\simeq K$, then $\dim_K(R/I)= \operatorname{length}_R(R/I).$

Set $r=\operatorname{length}_R(R/I)$. If $I=I_0\subset I_1\subset\cdots\subset I_r=R$ are ideals such that $I_j/I_{j-1}\simeq R/\mathfrak m_j$, with $\mathfrak m_j$ a maximal ideal for all $j=1,\dots,r$, then $\sqrt I_j=\mathfrak m$ for all $j=1,\dots,r-1$, therefore there exists a positive integer $t$ such that $\mathfrak m^{t}\subseteq I_j$ for all $j=0,1,\dots,r-1$. Then $\mathfrak m^t(I_j/I_{j-1})=0$ for all $j=1,\dots,r$, and thus $\mathfrak m^t(R/\mathfrak m_j)=0$ for all $j=1,\dots,r$. This shows that $\mathfrak m_j=\mathfrak m$ for all $j=1,\dots,r$, and we are done.